# specify path to a file inside java program

Tags: java

I have a program which requires path to a file. Currently, it's configured like this:

```
public class Main {

    private static final String ACOUSTIC_MODEL_PATH =
            "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us";
    private static final String DICTIONARY_PATH =
            "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict";
```

I have two questions:

1. What is this `resource:/path/goes/here` format, spefically `resource` word?
2. How do I specify path to a file on a disk?

I tried these options but file fails to be found:

```
private static final String DICTIONARY_PATH = "/d/cmudict-en-us.dict";
private static final String DICTIONARY_PATH = "file:/d/cmudict-en-us.dict";
private static final String DICTIONARY_PATH = "file://d/cmudict-en-us.dict";
```

Here is how supposedly the path is used (location is path here):

```
public static URL resourceToURL(String location) throws MalformedURLException {
    Matcher jarMatcher = jarPattern.matcher(location);
    if (jarMatcher.matches()) {
        String resourceName = jarMatcher.group(1);
        return ConfigurationManagerUtils.class.getResource(resourceName);
    } else {
        if (location.indexOf(':') == -1) {
            location = "file:" + location;
        }
        return new URL(location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show a code where `ACOUSTIC_MODEL_PATH` or `DICTIONARY_PATH` is actually used?

Comment: Why not try something like D:/cmudict-en-us.dict ?

Comment: @Alexandr, I tried, I get this error `InternalConfigurationException: Bad URL D:/cmudict-en-us.dictunknown protocol: d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `resources:/` is just an internal pattern which is used in your program (see `jarPattern` regular expression which should be declared somewhere in your program). It's not a common syntax of describing the URLs. But if this pattern does not match, the fallback implementation is to treat the string as the URL. Local file URLs are always started with `file:///` followed by normal path where backslashes are replaced with forward slashes.

Try the following string, it's a valid URL:

`"file:///d:/cmudict-en-us.dict"`

Comment: yeah, that worked. Can you please elaborate a bit on the differences between `resources:/edu...` and `file:///d:/` and why `file:///d/` is working while `file://d/` doesn't?

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell me what this line is for `location = "file:" + location;`? I thought I could use a path like this `///d/...` so that `file:` gets appended and I get valid URL `file:///d/...`, but I got an error showing concatenated path as `Loading dictionary from: file:/d/cmudict-en-us.dict`

Comment: Probably this branch would work on Unix systems where you have no drive letters, but was never tested on Windows. I guess, it's better to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify a path on a disk, you can use its absolute path like so:

```
String path = "C:\Folder\AnotherFolder\file.txt";
```

The problem with this, however, is that the '\' symbol can cause issues as java recognizes it as trying to mark an escape sequence like \n, \r, etc. To prevent this error, you can replace '\' with '\\' and the JVM will read it as a regular path. So instead of the code above, you can try this :

```
String path = "C:\\Folder\\AnotherFolder\\file.txt";
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried like that, I get this error: `InternalConfigurationException: Bad URL D:\cmudict-en-us.dictunknown protocol: d`

Comment: Yeah, the '\' character is used in Strings to signify an escape sequence with special values. In order to cancel it and let it be read as a plain backslash '\' , you need to use a double backslash '\\'

Comment: I know, I used double backslash.